# How to compare two vectors using a combination of OR logic and sum

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, numpy-ufunc

I am trying to apply a method that takes in two vectors and returns a resulting vector.

Below is an example input and expected result:

```
a = [ 1,  0, -1,  0,  0,  1]
b = [ 0,  0, -1,  0,  1, -1]

result = my_func(a, b)
# [ 1,  0, -1,  0,  1, 0]
```

My intial intuition is that a bitwise logic would be able to meet the above specifications. bitwise or seems the closest:

```
np.bitwise_or(a,b)
# array([ 1,  0, -1,  0,  1, -1])

np.bitwise_and(a,b)
# array([ 0,  0, -1,  0,  0,  1])

np.bitwise_xor(a,b)
# array([ 1,  0,  0,  0,  1, -2])
```

If a logical pairing is not possible, would the most efficient method of meeting the specification be applying a lambda to each index?

Answer (score 2):

This is the fastest solution I could find for arrays of type `np.int8` (arrays ∈ `[-1, 0, 1]` should be, for memory and computational efficiency) with less than 10k elements. For larger arrays clipping is more efficient than three additional operations.

Missing combinations were added to the example data.

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([ 1, -1, 0,  0, 1, -1, 0,  1, -1]).astype('int8')
b = np.array([ 0,  0, 1, -1, 1, -1, 0, -1,  1]).astype('int8')
# expected   [ 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 0,  0,  0]

(a | b) * (-a ^ b).view('bool')
```

Output

```
array([ 1, -1,  1, -1,  1, -1,  0,  0,  0], dtype=int8)
```

---

#### Benchmark results for arrays of growing size

[image: benchmark result]

Code used to run the [benchmark](https://pypi.org/project/perfplot/)

```py
perfplot.show(
    setup = lambda n: (np.random.choice([1, 0, -1], n).astype(np.int8),
                       np.random.choice([1, 0, -1], n).astype(np.int8)),
    kernels = [lambda a, b: (a | b) * (-a ^ b).view('bool'),
               lambda a, b: np.clip(a+b, -1, 1)],
    labels=['or and multiply xor', 'add and clip'],
    n_range=[2**k for k in range(10,25,2)],
    equality_check=np.array_equal
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can sum and [`clip`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html):

```
a = np.array([ 1,  0, -1,  0,  0,  1])
b = np.array([ 0,  0, -1,  0,  1, -1])

np.clip(a+b, -1, 1)
```

Output:

```
array([ 1,  0, -1,  0,  1,  0])
```

Comment: @achtunette did the answer not work for you? I see you unaccepted.